Wrong scale in QGIS Layout
Creating a map with multiple insets, but the scale for the main map and the insets are way too off the mark. Tried checking if the scalebar was linked to the correct map views and it was properly linked. Not sure what the problem is here? If the issue are my shapefiles, how do I check and how do fix it?
Project and shapefile CRS: EPSG:3857
Edit: Included screenshot of scalebar settings
Main shapefile used was downloaded from here: https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/world-administrative-boundaries/export/?location=2,14.26438,51.32813&basemap=jawg.light




You need to provide the scalebar setting as well as information on the CRS of your data, project and layout

probably because it is in degrees not metres

@IanTurton the crs for both my shapefiles and project is in EPSG:3857 which uses metres, is there anything else that can cause it to be in degrees?

@J.R I've edited the post to include them!

That is not 3857, Greenland is too small, your project is in 4326 so your scale is wrong
